# What is the differencies between oculus audio sdk and unity native spatial sound?

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I try, but I cannot hear any differencies from them, with or without `ONSP Audio Source`.

Why?
Do I need to export to gear vr, and wear the divice to get the differencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

There is differences. What you need to do is enable a plugin.

`OculusSpatializer` in **Audio Manager**